# Renaming .png files python

Tags: python, file, rename

Beginner question:

I am trying to rename .png files using:

```
import os

os.rename('x.png','y.png')
```

The error I get is:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified.

I am in the right directory, and so are the files.The strange this is, if I manually rename the file (for example to 'h.png') and use that variable name in the rename command, it **does** work.

I am confused...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WindowsError: \[Error 2\] The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324107/windowserror-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Comment: This is not related to duplicate name, the error for duplicate is FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'x.png' -> 'y.png'

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: python 2.7 is the version I use

Comment: probably you are working on directory with some permissions.
have you tried to change directory?

Comment: have tried giving the path of the file?

Comment: *“if I manually rename the file and use that variable name in the rename command”* – What do you mean with that?

Comment: right mouse click - rename

Comment: @robbah So you mean to say `os.rename('h.png','y.png')` *does* work?

Comment: probably you are working on directory with some permissions.

have you tried to change directory?

Comment: @Adi219 yeah it does, that is the strange thing

Comment: it seems as if the file needs to be edited first before being recognized by python? note: this is a file that I downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely that you got the `Can't find file` error because `'x.png'` isn't the absolute path.

Explicitly call `path` and `os.path.join(path, filename)` prior to calling the rename and it will work.

Try this:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'x.png'), 'y.png')
```

Comment: but he said that he is on the right directory, on my pc it's working from the same place, with no absolute path.

Comment: what do I enter at path?
path('location of folder') ?

Comment: @robbah Try `os.rename(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'x.png'), 'y.png')`

Comment: @Adi219 also doesn't work, however if I manually (right mouse click - rename) change the name and enter the name in that line, it does work!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `shutil` module?

```
import shutil
shutil.move('x.png','y.png')
```

But, be careful it doesn't rename your file but cut it with another name.