# How to overcome TGAN generator file not found error

Tags: python, xgboost, file-not-found

I'm using [TGAN](https://github.com/DAI-Lab/TGAN) generator to create synthetic data on tables.
While I'm running launcher.py, I'm getting the following error:

```
(xgboost) C:\Users\yoni\Desktop\TGAN-master\src>python launcher.py C:\Users\yoni\Desktop\TGAN-master\demo_config.json
[{'name': 'abalon', 'num_random_search': 10, 'train_csv': 'C:/Users/yoni/Desktop/data/abalon.csv', 'continuous_cols': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'epoch': 5, 'steps_per_epoch': 10000, 'output_epoch': 3, 'sample_rows': 10000}]
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yoni\Anaconda3\envs\xgboost\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\yoni\Anaconda3\envs\xgboost\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\yoni\Desktop\TGAN-master\src\launcher.py", line 22, in worker
    subprocess.call(task + ['--gpu', str(gpu_id)])
  File "C:\Users\yoni\Anaconda3\envs\xgboost\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\yoni\Anaconda3\envs\xgboost\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\yoni\Anaconda3\envs\xgboost\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "launcher.py", line 134, in <module>
    run_experiment(task)
  File "launcher.py", line 97, in run_experiment
    pool.map(worker, commands)
  File "C:\Users\yoni\Anaconda3\envs\xgboost\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 288, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\yoni\Anaconda3\envs\xgboost\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 670, in get
    raise self._value
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specifie
```

It seems like my csv and config file are fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WindowsError: \[Error 2\] The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324107/windowserror-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Comment: Thanks but its not.