# I'm using audiodiff to detect two audio files, whether they are different or similar

Tags: python, audio

This is the code that I'm using:

```
import audiodiff
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
fname1 = os.path.join(dir_path, 'SampleAudio_0.7mb.mp3')
fname2 = os.path.join(dir_path, 'SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3')

audiodiff.equal(fname1, fname2, ffmpeg_bin= None)
```

But i keep on getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop>python audio.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "audio.py", line 6, in <module>
    audiodiff.equal('SampleAudio_0.7mb.mp3', 'SampleAudio_0.7mb.mp3', ffmpeg_bin=None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\audiodiff\__init__.py", line 40, in equal
    return audio_equal(name1, name2, ffmpeg_bin) and tags_equal(name1,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\audiodiff\__init__.py", line 51, in audio_equal
    return checksum(name1, ffmpeg_bin) == checksum(name2, ffmpeg_bin)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\audiodiff\__init__.py", line 86, in checksum
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please help. And if you have some recommendation on audio detection, you're most welcome.

Comment: Please don't use images. Copy-paste the error text in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WindowsError: \[Error 2\] The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324107/windowserror-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)